# NameError when using a subclass in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass, nameerror

I have two .py files, one for the main(main.py) module and the other containing a class and its subclass (sub.py). From the main file, I use the class as follows.

```
## (main.py)
# Import the superclass
from sub import Class1
# Import the subclass
from sub import Class2
# Assign the object (it gives an error as described below)
myVariable=Class2()
```

where I write the two classes in sub.py as

```
## (sub.py)
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, nugget=0):
        self.eigval=nugget
        self.eigvec=nugget        
        self.explained=nugget
class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self, nugget=0):
        super().__init__(eigval, eigvec, explained)
        self.ppc=nugget
        self.vol=nugget
        self.corr=nugget
        self.cov=nugget
```

The error I'm getting is

```
NameError: name 'eigval' is not defined
```

although I an inheriting the variable eigval using the super() in the subclass.
Why would that be??

Comment: in `Class2.__init__`, the variable `eigval` **is not defined anywhere in that scope**. There is a `self.eigval`, but that wouldn't exist either. Furthermore, `super().__init__` would give you `Class1.__init__`, which takes *a single parameter*, but you are trying to pass 3... I thik you mean `super().__init__(nugget)`

Comment: >>I thik you mean super().__init__(nugget) 
Yes, that is what I meant. Thank you for your comment. I understood the problem and how to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything other than `nugget` to `Class2`

```
class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self, nugget=0):
        super().__init__(nugget)
        self.ppc=nugget
        self.vol=nugget
        self.corr=nugget
        self.cov=nugget
```

You are otherwise correct that `super().__init__` will call the `__init__` from `Class1` and therefore your `Class2` instance will have `eigval`, `eigvec`, and `explained` members.

```
>>> c = Class2()
>>> c.eigval
0
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I got the ideas :)